# How to convert a sql date format into xml date format:

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert `sql` date format into the following format:

```
2018-11-09T11:00:00+11:00
```

Answer (score 4):

Google is your friend :)

```
select CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),127)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or Convert this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ');
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert(varchar(10), Convert(Date,Datefield) ) +'T'+ Convert(varchar(8),convert(Time,Datefield,103))+@TimeOffset as EventDate